# How can I use the fontawesome package with XeLaTeX?

Tags: xetex, texlive, fontawesome

I am trying to compile a document using fontawesome with XeLaTeX (see this template https://github.com/ReScience/ReScience-submission/tree/master/article). I have Texlive 2016 installed in Ubuntu (installed directly from Texlive's homepage - not Ubuntu repositories). Texlive's `tlmgr` claims fontawesome is installed. I seem to find evidence of it here:

```
$ kpsewhich fontawesome.map
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/map/dvips/fontawesome/fontawesome.map
```

To debug the problem, I am trying to compile the following MWE (test.tex):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

using the command `xelatex test.tex`. Where it seems to reach the critical point, the log says:

```
kpathsea: Running mktextfm FontAwesome
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation F for FontAwesome.
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Need to update /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/map/fontname/special.map?
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input FontAwesome
This is METAFONT, Version 2.7182818 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded base=mf)


kpathsea: Running mktexmf FontAwesome
! I can't find file `FontAwesome'.
<*> ...our; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input FontAwesome

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...our; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input FontAwesome

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: FontAwesome.log: Ingen sådan fil eller filkatalog
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input FontAwesome' failed to make FontAwesome.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.


!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "FontAwesome" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................
```

I have run `updmap-sys` and `mktexlsr`, but that did not seem to help. `updmap-sys` said (among other things):

```
Files generated:
  /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvips/updmap:
       15796 2017-05-10 16:22:38 builtin35.map
       21269 2017-05-10 16:22:38 download35.map
     1688569 2017-05-10 16:22:39 psfonts_pk.map
     1903381 2017-05-10 16:22:38 psfonts_t1.map
     1903376 2017-05-10 16:22:38 ps2pk.map
          14 2017-05-10 16:22:39 psfonts.map -> psfonts_t1.map
  /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap:
     1903383 2017-05-10 16:22:39 pdftex_dl14.map
     1901718 2017-05-10 16:22:39 pdftex_ndl14.map
          15 2017-05-10 16:22:39 pdftex.map -> pdftex_dl14.map
  /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/updmap:
         319 2017-05-10 16:22:38 kanjix.map
```

Should there have been a xelatex folder as well?
What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Did you add that map to the updmap.cfg file before running updmap-sys?

Comment: No, I kind of assumed Texlive had taken care of all necessary set-up when I installed it. I see `Map fontawesome.map` in '/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg'. Is that correct?

Comment: That looks correct. If root owns you TeX distribution you need to use `sudo updmap-sys`.

Comment: According to Texlive recommendations, I have installed Texlive under a dedicated system user, 'tlusr'. I ran it as `sudo -u tlusr updmap-sys` and it seemed to work. I am going to amend my question above with some output from it...

Comment: xelatex doesn't need or use a map, it should use the real font.

Comment: So how do I make it do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

fontawesome loads the font by name: `\newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome}`. The font (fontawesome.otf) is in the texmf-tree in fonts/opentype/public/fontawesome.

On windows this is fine. Linux-Systems the texmf-tree isn't searched by fontconfig and so the font is not found.

### Possible solutions

#### 1. Use a file name:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\newfontfamily{\FA}{fontawesome.otf}
\begin{document}
\faHourglass
\end{document}
```

#### 2. Copy the font to your system font folder.

#### 3. Add the texmf trees to your fontconfig.

https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-340003.4.4

Comment: Trying your solution 1 still fails like before. On closer inspection, the is no 'fontawesome.otf' anywhere in my '/usr/local/texlive' tree. Where should that file have come from?

Comment: Oh, there is in /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/fontawesome/FontAwesome.otf. However, changing your example to `\newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome.otf}` does not help.

Comment: Sorry about the path. Normally it should work if you load it by file name. But I'm on windows so I can't test. Can you load it with `\setmainfont{FontAwesome.otf}`?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Everything I try seems to go wrong from where it says `kpathsea: Running mktextfm FontAwesome` in the log.

Comment: The log also says `/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Need to update /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/map/fontname/special.map?` How do I do that?

Comment: Ignore map-files. This is not your problem. The problem is why xelatex can't find and load the fontawesome.otf. Perhaps it is due to capitalization. It could matter on linux. Does `\newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome.otf}` work?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Should I not worry about `mktextfm` failing? This is where it seems to run off the tracks, judging by the log. I do not know what `mktextfm` is for.

Comment: Copying the font file to the system font folder (`/usr/share/fonts/opentype/`) finally solved it!

Comment: Solution 3 worked for me on Ubuntu 17.10. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The FontAwesome documentation says you must use the fontspec package to use with xelatex`\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\begin{document}
\faicon{500px}
\end{document}`

should do it. Note: see the documentation for a full list of all the macros it defines.

PS: The fully updated full TeX Live 2016 already contains fontawesome so I don't understand why you had to install it.

Comment: I do not recall actually installing the package myself. I just mentioned that tlmgr says it is installed.

Comment: Unfortunately, your example still gives the same error as quoted in my question...

Comment: Did you try making a copy of the .otf in your system fonts folder, as suggested?

Comment: I had not got to that point yet, but it actually works!

Comment: It also works without fontspec.

Comment: fontspec is loaded by fontawesome, you don't need to load additionally.